# Can't get the colon separator between figure number and caption in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

I have this in my _bookdown.yml for a word document I'm trying to render with bookdown. Even if don't create a _bookdown.yml file, I still don't get a ":" separator.

```
delete_merged_file: true
language:
  label:
   fig: 'Figuee '
   tab: 'TABLE '
ui:
  chapter_name: "Chapter "
```

but it shows up in the word document as:
Figuee 1 blah-blah

with no colon between the figure number and the caption. For the life of me, I don't see where that is specified nor where I can change it. I'm sure I'm missing something simple somewhere.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

other attached packages:
[1] bookdown_0.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1 knitr_1.20 xfun_0.3
```

Comment: Still actual - [epub is affected too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54915204/937095).

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/618) of **bookdown**, which [I just fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/7302e00069e4255de0c49f4622800c1bd7a1317f) on Github. Please try the development version:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```